# Read list of large .asc type files in python .memory related issue

Tags: python, numpy, analysis, txt

I have a folder with 50 large .asc type files each with size ~2.5Gb. These contains data from CAN signals ,how to read these files using python.I tried using numpy genfromtxt for reading files but having issues related to memory .What is the efficient way to read all the .asc files in folder into python for analysis purpose.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0):

You would feed the data into chunks with a for loop.
Cory Schafer's video demonstrates this in his video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh2ebFW8OYM&t=607s